# Print all values in a 3d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to print all values in a 3d array?

This is what I got but getting a null pointer exception:

```
        int i = 2;
        int x = 15;
        String[][][] arrays = new String[x][x][i];
        String arraytext = "hello";


            for (String[][] row: arrays)
             Arrays.fill(row, arraytext);


            for (int a = 0; a<=x; a++){
              for (int b = 0; b<=x; b++){
                  for (int j = 0; j<=i; j++)
                      {System.out.println(arrays[a][b][j]);}

                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: Check the stacktrace. If you don't know how, post the stacktrace here.

Comment: the `<=` is killing you.

Comment: where is sub defined?

Comment: For readers, the problem is `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String` at `Arrays.fill(row, arraytext);`.

Comment: sorry,, updated sub to b. the error i am getting is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: From your given code, there's no way to get `NullPointerException`. Please post the relevant code and the stacktrace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem filling your array. you are getting

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String at Arrays.fill(row, arraytext);
```

That is cause you are trying to add a String when is expected an String[][].
And for printing you can use [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) is your answer.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrays));
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][][] array3d = new String[10][10][10];

         for(String [] [] array2d : array3d){
             for(String[] array : array2d){
                 Arrays.fill(array, "hello");
             }
         }

         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array3d));

    }
```

Comment: That's not `NullPointerException`. Otherwise I would already closed this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this:

```
for (String[][] row: arrays)
     Arrays.fill(row, arraytext);
```

Is trying to pass `row`, which is a *double* array of strings, to a function expecting a single array of strings. To get the bottom level of your 3D array, you want this:

```
for (String[][] slice: arrays)
    for (String[] row: slice)
        Arrays.fill(row, arraytext);
```

You also have both issues addressed by other answers in your double loop: You'll get an index out of bounds unless you change the `<=`s to `<`, and `sub` isn't defined.

Comment: *Doesn't initialize any of the sub-arrays* that code initializes all the arrays, just try to print it after being declared and initialized.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I blame the empty coffee machine. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You're going out of bounds on your arrays, instead of `<=` try `<`.

```
for (int a = 0; a < x; a++){
          for (int b = 0; b < x; sub++){
              for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                  {System.out.println(arrays[a][b][j]);}

                                }
                            }
```

Also, what is `sub`? You're code snippet should show where you define this variable.

Comment: This doesn't address the exception being raised before this loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are experiencing off by 1 error (use `<` instead of `<=`):

```
for (int a = 0; a<x; a++){
   for (int b = 0; b<x; b++){
      for (int j = 0; j<i; j++)
      {System.out.println(arrays[a][b][j]);}

   }
}
```

Since you declared `arrays` as

```
String[][][] arrays = new String[x][x][i];
```

the bounds are from 0 to `x-1` for the first two indexes, and 0 to `i-1` for the thrid index.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're incrementing unknown variable sub rather than b in your second loop

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to replace a temporary value from copy-pastaing

```
for (int a = 0; a<=x; a++){
    for (int b = 0; b<=x; sub++){ // sub here <---
        for (int j = 0; j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.println(arrays[a][b][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also see @jh314 's answer, your doing the off by one error

Answer (score -1):

package academy.learnprogramming;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Print3DArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // declare & initialize an int 3D array firstInt3D
    int[][][] firstInt3D = {
            {{1,2}},
            {{3,4}},
            {{5,6,7,8},{9,10}},
            {{11},{12,13,14}},
    };



    // print all values of firstInt3D page by page
    int x = 0;
    for (int[][] accessPage: firstInt3D){
        System.out.println("page:" + x);
        if (x < firstInt3D.length) x++;
        for (int[] accessRow: accessPage){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(accessRow));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}